# How to parse an abbreviated date in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date

I am using Ruby 2.1 in a Rails 4.0.2 application. I need to convert a string into a valid Date object, but everything I try says it's an invalid date:

```
# in irb
date = 'Feb 9'
Date.strptime(date, '%m %-d')
# NoMethodError: undefined method `strptime' for Date:Class

# in Rails console
date = 'Feb 9'
Date.strptime(date, '%m %-d')
# ArgumentError: invalid date
#   from (irb):2:in `strptime'

date += ' ' + Time.now.year.to_s
Date.strptime(date, '%m %-d %Y')
# ArgumentError: invalid date
```

How can I parse a date in this abbreviated format?

Comment: i am seeing `'%m %-d'` a `-` before `d` that's not required

Comment: @NitinJ And will likely break `strptime`, the `-` is for `strftime`.

Comment: In the docs for strptime it says that it uses the same date formats from strftime. Maybe I read it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format string is wrong, it should be:

```
require 'date'
date = 'Feb 9'
Date.strptime(date, '%b %d').to_s
# => "2014-02-09"
```

`%m` would match a month number (1-12) while `%b` matches the abbreviated month name according to current locale. As the [Ruby documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-strptime) says, available formats are documented in [strptime(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strptime) manual page.

Or use the [`Date.parse`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-parse) method:

```
Date.parse(date).to_s
# => "2014-02-09"
```

**Update**: I didn't notice it before, the `-` modifier to match the unpadded day number breaks `strptime`:

```
Date.strptime('9', '%-d').to_s
# ArgumentError: invalid date

Date.strptime('9', '%d').to_s
# => "2014-02-09"
```

Answer (score 4):

"Feb" is not a valid month number.

```
[1] pry(main)> date = 'Feb 9'
"Feb 9"
[2] pry(main)> Date.strptime(date, "%b %d")
Sun, 09 Feb 2014
```

E.g.,

> ```
> %m - Month of the year, zero-padded (01..12)
>         %_m  blank-padded ( 1..12)
>         %-m  no-padded (1..12)
> %B - The full month name (``January'')
>         %^B  uppercased (``JANUARY'')
> %b - The abbreviated month name (``Jan'')
>         %^b  uppercased (``JAN'')
> %h - Equivalent to %b
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly parse the date:

```
date = 'Feb 9'

Date.parse date
```

Comment: (Correct, although in general we try to avoid "me too" answers when they're that far apart in time :)